# Can I read a RTF in FastReport?

Tags: delphi, report, fastreport

I want read a formated RTF file, and load to FastReport memo. I'm doing this:

```
var 
  ArquivoRTF : string; 
  Conteudo : TStringList; 
begin 
  ArquivoRTF := DiretorioDoExecutavel+'RTFTEMP.RTF'; 
  Conteudo := TStringList.Create; 
  Conteudo.LoadFromFile(ArquivoRTF); 
  Desc := TfrxMemoView.Create(Page); 
  Desc.Name:= 'Desc'+IntToStr(I); 
  Desc.Text := Conteudo.Text; 
  Desc.Height:= 20; 
  Desc.Left:= Left; 
  Desc.Align:= baWidth; 
  Desc.Top:= 1;
```

Read, but, not formated. How a can red formated? I'm using Delphi 2010 and FastReport 4.9 Thanks from Brazil.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a TfrxRichView instead of TfrxMemoView to show Rtf data.